# Strip in collect on splitted array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
str = "1, hello,2"
puts str
arr = str.split(",")
puts arr.inspect
arr.collect { |x| x.strip! }
puts arr.inspect
```

produces the following result:

```
1, hello,2
["1", " hello", "2"]
["1", "hello", "2"]
```

This is as expected. The following code:

```
str = "1, hello,2"
puts str
arr = (str.split(",")).collect { |x| x.strip! }
puts arr.inspect
```

Does however produce the following output:

```
1, hello,2
[nil, "hello", nil]
```

Why do I get these "nil"? Why can't I do the .collect immediately on the splitted-array?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For what it's worth, you can do the same thing using regex `"1, hello,2".split(/\,\s|\,/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`#collect`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect) method will return an array of the values returned by each block's call. In your first example, you're modifying the actual array contents with `#strip!` and use those, while you neglect the return value of `#collect`.

In the second case, you use the `#collect` result. Your problem is that [**`#strip!`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip-21) will either return a string or `nil`, depending on its result – especially, it'll return `nil` if the string wasn't modified.

Therefore, use [**`#strip`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) (without the exclamation mark):

```
1.9.3-p194 :005 > (str.split(",")).collect { |x| x.strip }
 => ["1", "hello", "2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `#strip!` returns `nil` if the string was not altered.

In your early examples you were not using the result of `#collect,` just modifying the strings with `#strip!`. Using `#each` in that case would have made the non-functional imperative loop a bit more clear.  One normally uses `#map` / `#collect` only when using the resulting new array.

You last approach looks good, you wrote a functional map but you left the `#strip!` in ... just take out the `!`.